# How to set up a PATH on mac OS X in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have an .jar file that communicates with a web service. I have to set up the path on terminal (Mac OS X Yosemite) so it could communicate to it, I do know how to set it up on windows OS by just going to the "Environment Variables". But on OS X is more complicated, please help me.

variables name is: WS_3619_TICTACTOE
path is http://localhost:8080/07.WSTicTacToe/webapi/tictactoeresource/

Im using tomcat as my web server.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do it in the permanent way you have edit or create your .bashrc or .bash_profile profile file.

Open Terminal in your home directory (~), then type `nano .bash_profile`.

Then insert the following `export PATH=/07.WSTicTacToe/webapi/tictactoeresource:$PATH`

Save the file. Close - open the Terminal.

In the command prompt ensure that path include by typing `echo $PATH`

Comment: You'd need to re-*source* that file with `. ~/.bash_profile` or whatever before it took effect.  Alternatively close then re-open Terminal.app.

Comment: Absolutely! Added to the answer. Thanks!